Daily events action type
I am trying to create a system for daily events in Unity, but I am facing an obstacle where performance and memory are very sensitive for me, and I cannot choose between Action or delegate, noting that the function will be called with a parameter.
1- Which one is better for performance, consumes less memory, and does not consume additional memory during execution? Or is there a better option than both of them?
2- Is this the correct way to create the action (Lambda expression), and is there a better way?
NightLightsManager script: This script is an example of creating an action for any daily event.
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NightLightsManager : DailyEvent
{
    public override List<DailyEventAction> DailyEventActions { get; protected set; } = new List<DailyEventAction>();
    DailyEventAction _dailyEventActionToAdd = new DailyEventAction();

    [SerializeField] private List<NightLightsEvent> _nightLightsEvents;

    [SerializeField] private Light[] _streetLights;
    void Init()
    {
        if (_nightLightsEvents.Count < 1)
            return;

        NightLightsEvent nightLightsEvent = new NightLightsEvent();

        _nightLightsEvents.Sort();
        for (int i = 0; i < _nightLightsEvents.Count; i++)
        {
            if (DailyEventActions.FindIndex(localDailyEvntAction => localDailyEvntAction.Name == _nightLightsEvents[i].Name) < 0)
            {
                int currentIndex = i;

                _dailyEventActionToAdd.DailyEvent = this;
                _dailyEventActionToAdd.Name = _nightLightsEvents[i].Name;

                nightLightsEvent = _nightLightsEvents[currentIndex];
                _dailyEventActionToAdd.Action = () => ExecuteEvent(nightLightsEvent);
                _dailyEventActionToAdd.TimeInMinutes = _nightLightsEvents[i].Hour * 60 + _nightLightsEvents[i].Minute;

                DailyEventActions.Add(_dailyEventActionToAdd);
            }
        }
    }

    void ExecuteEvent(NightLightsEvent eventData)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _streetLights.Length; i++)
        {
            _streetLights[i].enabled = eventData.IsLightsOn;
        }

        Debug.Log($"Invoking {eventData.Name} | {eventData.IsLightsOn} lights at: {TimeManager.Instance.CurrentTotalMinutes}");
    }
}

DailyEventAction script: It holds the data of the action to be invoke, such as the name, time, and a reference to the action function.
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public struct DailyEventAction : IComparable<DailyEventAction>
{
    public DailyEvent DailyEvent;
    public string Name;
    public Action Action;

    [SerializeField, Range(0, 1439)] private int _timeInMinutes;
    public int TimeInMinutes
    {
        get => _timeInMinutes;
        set => _timeInMinutes = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, 1439);
    }

    public DailyEventAction(DailyEvent dailyEvent, string name, Action action, int hour, int minute)
    {
        DailyEvent = dailyEvent;
        Name = name;
        Action = action;
        _timeInMinutes = Mathf.Clamp(hour, 0, 23) * 60 + Mathf.Clamp(minute, 0, 59);
    }

    public DailyEventAction(DailyEvent dailyEvent, string name, Action action, int timeInMinutes)
    {
        DailyEvent = dailyEvent;
        Name = name;
        Action = action;
        _timeInMinutes = timeInMinutes;
    }

    public int CompareTo(DailyEventAction other)
    {
        return TimeInMinutes - other.TimeInMinutes;
    }
}

NightLightsEvent script: It holds the data that will be used as a parameter in the function and executes the function based on it.
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public struct NightLightsEvent : IComparable<NightLightsEvent>
{
    public string Name;

    [SerializeField, Range(0, 23)]
    private int _hour;
    public int Hour
    {
        get => _hour;
        set => _hour = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, 23);
    }

    [SerializeField, Range(0, 59)]
    private int _minute;
    public int Minute
    {
        get => _minute;
        set => _minute = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, 59);
    }

    public bool IsLightsOn;

    public NightLightsEvent(string name, int hour, int minute, bool isLightsOn)
    {
        Name = name;
        _hour = Mathf.Clamp(hour, 0, 23);
        _minute = Mathf.Clamp(minute, 0, 59);

        IsLightsOn = isLightsOn;
    }

    public int CompareTo(NightLightsEvent other)
    {
        return (Hour * 60 + Minute) - (other.Hour * 60 + other.Minute);
    }
}


"I cannot choose between Action or delegate" → If you look up the docs for System.Action<T>, you'll find that Action is a delegate type. So, it's not clear to me what distinction you're making here — can you illustrate the alternative you're weighing?

I can promise you, with outmost certainty, that the performance / memory difference between Action and a generic delegate as constructs is so negligible it might literally not even be measurable in the context of a real application. In fact there might literally not be any difference, I don't have Jon Skeet levels of C# knowledge unfortunately. Choose freely.
As for the lambda creation, yes that looks correct.
